# Experienced HTML/CSS programmer trying to "jump" to dynamic stuff

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, cpanel, roundcube

I've mastered the art of the static website, and now I'm picking up books on PHP, SQL, PEAR, etc so I can get a better handle of making a database-driven website. Now, I'm helping a small startup company get everything necessary off the ground while paying the minimum for third party help (I have yet to look into odesk or elance).

There are two main sites (we'll call them .com and .biz)
.com is the corporate site (an independently run wordpress site with cpanel & email accounts)
.biz is the indiviual reseller's site (expensive software program generating wildcard subdomains with replicated websites and a "virtual office" on asp.net and sql server... this is where our e-commerce is done)

With what I have, right out of the box, there are THREE different logins when there should only be ONE login to get you logged in to interact on the blog, check your webmail, and enter into your virtual office.

All I want is to be able to tie everything in together. Just like this website, after i've logged in once, all of these things are possible by calling php. If the cookie knows who you are, you're automatically logged into all three.. etc etc. Maybe even a header that displays how many messages are in your inbox FROM the wordpress site.

Here's my question.. and I apologize in advance for how uneducated this may sound.

What type of programmer should I turn to for this kind of assistance? I know this will require PHP & SQL, but should I expect any other languages to make this possible? Unless there are clear-cut tutorials available online, I've got to hire a programming ninja that can translate these needs into code. Thanks for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends on how your solution to these tasks looks like but yes it could probably be done simple with just php/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into web services in order to help your sites communicate.   This can be done via PHP.